# Centralização na vertical com translate

Tags: html, css

Meus caros, sempre usei a tática abaixo para centralizar meus elementos na vertical que estão contidos em algo com position absolute, mas de um tempo para cá ele não vem mais funcionando, o elemento simplesmente não centraliza mas passa muito do que seria o centro.

Eu estou fazendo algo de errado ou esse método já não funfa mais?

```
position: relative
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Estou fazendo assim:

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.content .central {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<section class="content">

  <div class="central">

    <h1><b>Texto de teste</b></h1>

  </div>


</section>
```

Comment: Poderia fazer um [mcve] demonstrando o problema?

Comment: Pode colocar o html e o css completo

Comment: Adicionei o código na pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha o que acontece quando vc declara o `translate` 2x, o browser só reconhece o segundo, pois ele sobrescreve o primeiro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O correto seria usar o *long-hand* assim:

```
transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
```

Ou o *short-hand* assim:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Onde o o primeiro 50% é no eixo X e o segundo 50% é o eixo Y

Coloquei uma borda apenas para vc ver que o elemento está centralizado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.content {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

}

.content .central {
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<section class="content">

    <div class="central">

        <h1><b>Texto de teste</b></h1>

    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Entendi o erro que estava cometendo! Resposta completíssima, obg!

Comment: @LeonardoHenrique sem problemas, tenha em mente que isso vale para outras propriedades como background por exemplo. []´s